# "Thousands of thousands" vs. "Thousands upon thousands"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, numbers

Is "thousands of thousands" grammatically correct? Why does it seem that "thousands upon thousands" sounds better, even though the former is closer to the logical truth? Is there any difference at all?

Comment: The answers by _AUAnonymous_ and _pavium_ hit on the crux of the matter. I might also add, that to me "thousands upon thousands" has a stronger connotation of compounding, and possibly even of indefinite _thousands_. I would be inclined to use the former in a literal sense and the latter in a more figurative sense.

Comment: I have never heard "thousands of thousands". Only "thousands upon thousands" and "thousands and thousands".

Comment: @tenfour The phrase "thousands of thousands", is in the King James Bible. It means "Millions".

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an English language question site, but to answer this question in terms of math:

```
"Thousands of thousands" = 1000 x 1000 (or more)
"Thousands upon thousands" = A x 1000 (where A is any relatively small number)
```

So in simple terms, "thousands of thousands" is a lot more than "thousands upon thousands", although I do agree with you the latter does sound better.

Comment: Well, actually your first equation should be `X * 1000 x 1000` where `X` is greater than 1. But, strict math aside I think this would be a normal interpretation of `of`. Consider an easier example like "5 bags *of* 5". Or consider expressions like "the 3rd daughter *of* the 5th son". So I would say *of* tends to always refer to multiplication or sets of some kind.

Comment: nitpicking version: `m x 10^3 x n x 10^3` vs `m x 10^3 + n x 10^3` where `m, n ∈ {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`

Answer (score 5):

To my ears, *thousands of thousands* is a really large number (possibly a million) at a *specific moment* (as already indicated in other answers)

However, *thousands upon thousands* might imply a progress in time: a *thousand* followed by another *thousand* later followed by yet another *thousand* even later and so on.

Answer (score 4):

To my ear, *thousands upon thousands* could just mean "several thousands" or "many thousands".

I've never understood it to mean *thousands **of** thousands*, which would amount to millions — which the speaker would probably use, if that was meant.

Comment: the main reason for thousands of thousands is that the concept of millions is only good for abstract readers and conceptual thinkers, where much wider audience has direct experience with thousands, so 'thousands of thousands' *can* be more easily imagined compared to millions.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to me that 'thousands upon thousands' gives the impression of an innumerable number and then just to make it profoundly clear that it is a number beyond a 'name' ... Tack on a 'thousands of thousands' onto that innumerable number!

Comment: They are not used together-  the question asks about one ***vs*** the other.